# Laravel 5.2 Request returns null AJAX

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, laravel-5

Someone please help !  This is a crazy error I am getting in Laravel. Ok i have a form and I am trying have .doc .pdf and a image file to get uploaded to the server. So in my html i deceived my in input as  a file using the type attribute. When I try to submit the form using ajax new FormData() I see the file being sent in the header of the HTTPS request in the console but the response from the server does not show the file at all. Heres a look at my code in my html.

```
 <form id="form"  method = "POST"  enctype="multipart/form-data" action="{{url('/SetUp/Save')}}" >

<div id = "box" class="container dark well  dataBox textBox2">
<script type="text/javascript">
 num = 1; // only show  the  first  box  and hide the others VM keeping the num var for use later 
</script>

 @for($i = 1; $i <= $amount; $i++)

<div id = {{"panel".$i}} class="panel panel-default">

<div class="panel-heading">

   <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger left">Remove
<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash" aria-hidden="true"></span>
 </button>

 <h3 class="panel-title"><strong> Location {{$i}}</strong></h3>
 </div>
<div class=" pBody panel-body">  

  <div class="row">
<div class="form-group col-lg-6">
    <label  class = "control-label" label-default="Address" for="Address">Address
    </label>
    <input type="text" name= "Address[{{$i}}]" class="form-control" placeholder="Address">

  </div>

  <div class="form-group  top col-lg-6">
    <label class = "control-label" label-default="City" for="City">City</label>
    <input type="text" name = "City[{{$i}}]" class="form-control"
    placeholder="City">
    </div>
 </div>


<div class="row">
<div class="form-group col-lg-6 ">
    <label class = "control-label" label-default="Picture" for="Picture">Picture</label>
    <input type="file" name = "Picture[{{$i}}]" class= "form-control" id="Picture"
    placeholder="Picture">
</div>
```

Controller

```
     public function saveData(PostRequest $request) {





    }
```

Post Request

```
    namespace App\Http\Requests;

    use App\Http\Requests\Request;

    use Log;


    class PostRequest extends Request
    {
        /**
         * Determine if the user is authorized to make this request.
         *
         * @return bool
         */
        public function authorize()
        {
            return true;
        }

        /**
         * Get the validation rules that apply to the request.
         *
         * @return array
         */

       public function wantsJson()
            {
                return true;
            }

        public function response(array $errors) 
           {  


                   return response()->json($errors);
           }


     public function rules() {

        $rules = [];

        var_dump($this->request); // request object print out 

         var_dump($this->request->get('Picture'); // return NULL to console 




    foreach($this->request->get('Picture') as $key => $val) // error 500 meaning Picture is null. 
    {
        $rules['Picture.'.$key] = 'required|image';
    }
   }
```

As you can see I am trying to validate the request but i wind up with an error. 
and when I var_dump the request I get null and its not showing up in the var_dump here is a look at the var_dump print out

```
             object(Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\ParameterBag)#194 (1) {
              ["parameters":protected]=>
              array(15) {
                ["Address"]=>
                array(5) {
                  [1]=>
                  string(0) ""
                  [2]=>
                  string(0) ""
                  [3]=>
                  string(0) ""
                  [4]=>
                  string(0) ""
                  [5]=>
                  string(0) ""
                }
                ["City"]=>
                array(5) {
                  [1]=>
                  string(0) ""
                  [2]=>
                  string(0) ""
                  [3]=>
                  string(0) ""
                  [4]=>
                  string(0) ""
                  [5]=>
                  string(0) ""
                }

            }
```

and here is my ajax

```
      /////////////send data to server 

      $("#form").on("submit",function(event) {
         console.log("Fire");

      $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: '/SetUp/Save',
        //data: $(this).serialize(), // put the data in url form // send data over 
        data: new FormData( this ), // send data including file input to xml to process for sever 
        processData: false,
        contentType: false,
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function(data){

           HolderArray = []

           JsonKeys = Object.keys(data);


           for(x in data){

               HolderArray.push(data[x])

           }



           for (var i = 0; i < JsonKeys.length;  i++) {

               holder = JsonKeys[i].replace(".","[");

              $("[name='"+holder+"]'"+"]").parent().addClass(' animated shake has-error') .append(' <span class="help-block"> <strong>'+HolderArray[i]+'</strong></span>')                   

           }

        },
        error: function(data){
          var errors = data.responseJSON;
          console.log(errors);
          // Render the errors with js ...
        }

      });


      return false;

      });
```

No Picture to be found. it seem like the request object is not getting file  input.  I have been searching online and no luck at solving this problem. Please help i am new to Laravel as well so please help me out . Thank You

Comment: In PHP, files are getting separated from regular parameters, they are in `$_FILES`. Laravel has a method to get the information about the file called `file`. So you should be able to get the infos with `$this->request->file('Picture')`. Sorry I'm not a Laravel user, only stumbled over some related questions on here and read a bit of the Laravel docs - so I'm not absolutely sure if that works.

Comment: I tried that but i get this error here ......                                              FatalErrorException in PostRequest.php line 45:
Call to undefined method Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\ParameterBag::file() i am baffle by this error

Comment: why not use ` Illuminate\Http\Request` ? See https://laravel.com/docs/5.1/requests

Answer (score 0, accepted):

aha i figured out my problem! in my Post Request class instead of calling

```
         $this->request->get('Picture'); // this will return null 
         // But 
          $this->file('Picture');// will return the file and show that the file has been uploaded.  It seems like the file does not bind the to request object.
```

now instead of validating  my field like so

```
        foreach($this->request->get('Picture') as $key => $val)
            {
                  $rules['Picture.'.$key] = 'required';
                       }  // this gives a null error
```

I changed that to this and it works

```
          foreach($this->file('Picture') as $key => $val)
                {
              $rules['Picture.'.$key] = 'required';
                    }
```

it works !!! .

thanks for your help !!!